# RegExp in firestore function onCall

Tags: regex, firebase, function

I'd like to use RegExp onCall but it returns an error

```
exports.handler = (data,context) => {

    console.log(data.terminRozpoczecia);

    //uzytkownik zalogowany?
    if(!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'unauthenticated',
        'Tylko dla zalogowanych uytkowników'
        );
    }

    //termin rozpoczecia
    const terminRozpoczeciaPatt = new RegExp("/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.20[2-9][0-9] (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/");
    if (!terminRozpoczeciaPatt.test(data.terminRozpoczecia)) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'invalid-argument',
            'Nieprawidłowy format daty: Termin rozpoczęcia'
        );
    }

    return {status: 'OK'};
 }
```

It's return

> Unhandled error ReferenceError: functions is not defined

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found solution

```
const terminRozpoczeciaPatt = /^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\.(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.20[2-9][0-9] (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/;
const terminRozpoczecia = data.terminRozpoczecia;
    if (!terminRozpoczeciaPatt.exec(terminRozpoczecia)) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'invalid-argument',
            'Nieprawidłowy format daty: Termin rozpoczęcia'
        );
    }
```